# Laravel parsing a nested serialized query string

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, http, laravel-5

I'm trying to pass a nested set of query params to my Laravel 5.1 API. I'm using `$httpParamSerializer(params)` the serialize the object, which seems to do it correctly as the `GET` looks like:

```
GET "http://my-api.localhost/1.0/categories?category=Anatomy&category=Consent+Forms"
```

Yet, when I return the `$request` from Laravel, it shows only one of the properties:

```
Object {category: "Consent Forms"}
```

Why is this?

Angular Frontend:

```
        var filters = {
            category : ['Anatomy', 'Consent Forms']
        };

        Category.getCategories(filters).then(function(res) {
            // Object {category: "Consent Forms"}
            console.log('CATEGORIES', res.data);
```

Angular HTTP Request:

```
        getCategories: function(params) {
            var qs = $httpParamSerializer(params);
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: url + ver + '/categories?' + qs,
                headers: Auth.getOAuthHeader(),
                cache: true
            });
        },
```

Laravel:

```
public function getCategories(Request $request) {
    $input = $request->all();
    return $input;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the default behavior of `$httpParamSerializer` is to output the same key in the url for each value of the array, which PHP handles on a last-set basis so only the last key value par is set.

From the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializer):

```
{'foo': ['bar', 'baz']} results in foo=bar&foo=baz (repeated key for each array element)
```

You can use the `$httpParamSerializerJQLike` service to handle the process of url-encoding data that is inspired by jQuery's `.param()`.

With `$httpParamSerializerJQLike` the params:

```
category : ['Anatomy', 'Consent Forms']
```

will become:

```
?category[]=Anatomy&category[]=Consent+Forms
```

To use [`$httpParamSerializerJQLike`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$httpParamSerializerJQLike) you need to inject it in the Controller. Eg

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $http, $httpParamSerializer, $httpParamSerializerJQLike) {
```

The use it to serialize your data:

```
getCategories: function(params) {
    var qs = $httpParamSerializerJQLike(params);
    return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: url + ver + '/categories?' + qs,
        headers: Auth.getOAuthHeader(),
        cache: true
    });
},
```